# Google adwords conversion tracking - How to track 2 different onclick conversions on same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tracking, google-ads-api

I would like to track 2 different onclick conversions on the same page. Google's example tracking code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      /* <![CDATA[ */
      goog_snippet_vars = function() {
        var w = window;
        w.google_conversion_id = 12345678;
        w.google_conversion_label = "abcDeFGHIJklmN0PQ";
        w.google_conversion_value = 13.00;
        w.google_conversion_currency = "USD";
        w.google_remarketing_only = false;
      }
      // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
      goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
        goog_snippet_vars();
        window.google_conversion_format = "3";
        var opt = new Object();
        opt.onload_callback = function() {
        if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
          window.location = url;
        }
      }
      var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
      if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
        conv_handler(opt);
      }
    }
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
    </script>
```

And the example onclick code looks like this:

```
<a onclick="goog_report_conversion
    ('http://www.example.com/whitepapers/a.pdf')"
    href="#" >DOWNLOAD NOW</a>
```

I can't see anything in the onlick code that would differentiate between the 2 different onclick tracking scripts I have.

Is there a way to set it up so each click conversion is sent to the correct script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem and spent hours trying different solutions, but nothing seemed to work. Finally called Google Support and they had to check with their specialist to tell me that Google AdWords **DOES NOT support** multiple OnClick conversion codes on the same page.

Alternatively, you can track 1 OnClick conversion using Google Adwords on a single page and then use Google Analytics to track the other OnClick events (see [Goals](http://www.gravitatedesign.com/blog/event-tracking-google-analytics/)). Make sure your Google Analytics and Google Adwords account are [linked](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961?hl=en) before doing this.

HTH